# Windows Server denied policy administrator deadlock

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy

I was trying to deny some administrative tools access to certain domain user, so I opened the policies manager and enabled the deny control panel access, and other (including MMC) in local user...

Now, I didn't imagine that the rule will apply to the Administrator too! Now I want to restore the rule, but I think that I disabled the policies editor too...

I don't know what to do. I tried using the domain administrator with no luck, I have the same results...
I tried to restore the default local policies settings with this command:

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
```

But it gives me a message that some policies could no be restored and the log has many "Access Denied" messages...

What can I do?

Comment: 1) Re-install - 2) Take some time to contemplate todays lesson learned

Comment: So... There is no way back that reinstall. That's so bad :(

Comment: I'm not saying that it's impossible to recover from, just that re-installing would by far be the safest and fastest option

Comment: All right. Anyway I really learned a lesson today ha ha. Thanks

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  good work at being totally wrong on this one!

Comment: @tonyroth Apart from the 9 hours it took to solve, sure - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved the issue executing the Policies Editor from the Run...

```
Run->gpedit.msc
```

That way, I was able to open the Policies Editor that was hidden because I was Enabled the policy that Denies PC Configuration and Control Panel. I can disable the policy right now...